# Getting Error: pexpect not installed, try: pip install pexpect

Tags: pexpect, rundeck

Configuring Rundeck remote windows node using py-winrm.  Successfully configured using Basic Auth, then trying to configure to use Kerberos I started getting an error meeting the requirements for Py-Winrm.

Rundeck 3.3.11 with py-winrm on Windows Server 2016 Server. Getting an error connecting to remote host running a Command job.

Error: pexpect not installed, try: pip install pexpect

Python3.9.6
verified pexpect 4.8.0 installed using pip list

I've tried;
uninstalled/reinstalled pexpect and Python and restarted Windows after Python reinstall and Rundeck Service after each change.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: Did you try using pip3 command? pip3 list

Comment: I just tried pip3 list  - and the result is the same.  It shows pexpext 4.8.0 is installed.  Thank you.

Comment: Could you run your job in debug mode and share the full stacktrace here?

Comment: Another input: please go to Project Settings > Edit Configuration and click on the "Default Node Executor" tab, (make sure that you're using "WinRM Node Executor Python" as default node executor, on in the "Python Interpreter" textbox put the python3 binary full path. Same for the "Default file copier" tab.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Project Settings > Edit Configuration and click on the "Default Node Executor" tab, (make sure that you're using "WinRM Node Executor Python" as default node executor), on the "Python Interpreter" textbox put the python3 binary full path (the python3 path that you're used to installing the `pexpect` module). Same for the "Default file copier" tab.